# jQuery .keyup() function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm not receiving any output from this code. What could be the error.

**terminal.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="/css/webterminal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function shell_execute(str) {     
  $.ajax({
    url: 'exec.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
      q: str
    },
    success: function (response) {
      $('#txtOut').append(response);

  });
}
</script>
</head
<body">
    <div class="container">

    <h2>UNIX Web Based Terminal 1.0</h2>
        <br />
    <p><b>output</b></p>
<form>
<span id="User"></span>< <input type="text" id="txtcmd" onkeyup="shell_execute(this.value)" class="textbox" size="20" />
</form>
<div class="output">
<p><span id="txtOut"></span></p>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**exec.php**

```
<?php

$q=$_GET["q"]; 
$output=shell_exec($q);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Your URL doesn't match the name of the file you're listing... a typo? Also, can we see the rest of your HTML? Where's the input element you're binding to?

Comment: In your title you mention the .keyUp() function. Is that the function that is not being triggered, or is it the ajax call that doesn't respond.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634122/appending-the-contents-of-a-unix-command-to-a-div-tag
I think it, would have been easier to finish this topic in the original, instead of starting a new one...

Comment: You DO know that your closing head markup is NOT closed properly right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value from your text input element and put that into `str` before you pass it to your script.

Like:

```
 var str = $("#txtcmd").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"/>
```

Close your script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: what effect does it have? on closing the tag like this ?

Comment: @Naveed Butt - For some reason, this is the required syntax to ensure it always picks up the script correctly, when you don't the script will not run properly.

Answer (score 2):

In terminal.html what is `str` for ???

you should pass some value to get the output

try `echoing $_GET['q'];` you will come to know

Comment: When do you ever call shell_execute()?

Answer (score 2):

Not specifically your issue I believe but I would take the 
`onkeyup="shell_execute(this.value)"`  out of the markup and put in the script part a jQuery event handler:

```
$("#txtcmd").keyup(function(){
  shell_execute($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but this is also the problem as well..

```
function shell_execute(str) {     
  $.ajax({
    url: 'exec.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
      q: str
    },
    success: function (response) {
      $('#txtOut').append(response);
     } <------------ You were missing this.
  });
}
```